# How is replace done in python for quote backslash?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following shows what I want to do:

```
>>> "input '\t' quote tab".replace("'\\",'replace')
"input '\t' quote tab"
>>>
```

The output shows that the quote and backslash are not replaced.

I wonder why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\t` is one character (as pointed out by @MaLiN2223). If you want it to be "raw" then you need to use raw strings:

```
>>> r"input '\t' quote tab".replace("'\\", 'replace')
"input replacet' quote tab"
```

The following "escaped sequences" are treated as one-character unless an 'r' or 'R' string is used (taken from the [python3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) and the [python2 equivalent](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)):

```
\newline    Ignored      
\\          Backslash (\)    
\'          Single quote (')     
\"          Double quote (")     
\a          ASCII Bell (BEL)     
\b          ASCII Backspace (BS)     
\f          ASCII Formfeed (FF)      
\n          ASCII Linefeed (LF)      
\N{name}    Character named name in the Unicode database (Unicode only)      
\r          ASCII Carriage Return (CR)   
\t          ASCII Horizontal Tab (TAB)   
\uxxxx      Character with 16-bit hex value xxxx (Unicode only)
\Uxxxxxxxx  Character with 32-bit hex value xxxxxxxx (Unicode only)
\v          ASCII Vertical Tab (VT)      
\ooo        Character with octal value ooo
\xhh        Character with hex value hh
```

Comment: Since OP's question tags include python 2 I would change documentation to [https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: Uh, I wouldn't go so far as to include 2.4 documentation but point taken! I've added the python2.7 documentation page.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. This was first google link :( I edited my coment. 
However I wish that we just let python2 die

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because python desn't see this particual `\` as `\` but as part of `\t`. And since `\t` is single character, you cannot replace part of it.

Where as in this example:

```
"input '\t' quote tab'\\".replace("'\\",'replace')
```

Output will be:

```
"input '\t' quote tabreplace"
```